# BCM43228 not working after reboot

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I am posting this thread after trying the solutions already provided in the forum but it does not work for me.

1. Installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS version on Dell Latitude E6420 with a broadcom wifi devicie BCM43228
2. After install I went to `system settings` >> `software and updates` and `additional drivers and selected the proprietary driver from bcmwl-kernel-source`
3. As soon as the install was done then the wifi was enabled and I was able to connect
4. How ever when I shutdown and start the system wifi destinations are not being shown anymore
5. I also tried manually installing the driver using the following steps

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic   
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```

reboot and no luck

tried also install of `broadcom-sta-common`

still no wifi destinations are shown.

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]

what exactly am I doing wrong?

Does anyone know if Avahi impacts the discovery of Wifi destinations. I am wondering if that is caused by Avahi shutting down network discovery services due to local domain naming issue (local).

Thanks,

Wilson

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured out what is going on. The reboot did not cause the issue. It is that the blacklist conf file, that is created by the install of bcmwl-kernel-source, is wiped off by ubuntu upgrade. 
I could use the b43 drivers itself but a quick check of download speeds show that bcmwl-kernel-source is faster. Just recreate this file if this happens to you.

wthankachan@wilson-E6420:/etc/modprobe.d$ cat blacklist-bcm43.conf

## Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost.

blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

Update 9/12/2015: The issue came back again :

[    3.181647] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    3.181650] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    3.185408] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel